# navigationOptions weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[image]First time open the page, navigationOptions futures don't work but when I run props.navigation.navigate methot or ctrl+s in main navigation file, it works

[[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. I move the navigationOptions out of the main function.